# Need divs side by side, but "float: left" isn't working

Tags: css, html, css-float

What I'm trying to achieve is three divs in a row with different, specific widths and equal heights.  Two of them actually have content, and the middle one just contains a vertical spacer image.  These three divs are contained in a "slide" div, along with other slides.  The slides are all in one container div and controlled with JavaScript, hiding all but one slide at a time.  Note that the slides are not the problem, but rather the layout of their contents.  Currently, I can only make the three divs inside the second slide stack on top of each other, and yet it *works perfectly fine with four divs in the first slide*.  Here's what I've tried so far and hasn't worked:

- `float:left;` on each div
- `float:left;` on first two and then `float:right` on last
- `display:inline;` on each div
- `display:inline-table;`
- lowering widths so they're not exact
- removing all margins
- `clear:left;` after third div
- `clear:both;` after third div
- using `class` instead of `id` (which actually has changed things)
- various combinations of the above

I'm using Eclipse for code and Safari on Mac OS X to test; everything is up to date.  Any help is greatly appreciated as I have been trying to get this to work for two and a half days now.  Here is my code, if you need any more of it to find the problem, please let me know.

HTML:

```
     <div id="container">
         <div class="slide1">

            <div id="news-content">
                <div id="news-img">
                    <img src="album_example.png" />
                </div>
                <div id="news-img-description">
                    <h2 align="left">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                    <p align="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam consequat dictum pharetra. Cras porta.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="news-vr">
                    <img src="light_vr.png" />
                </div>
                <div id="news-feed">

                </div>
            </div>


        </div>


        <div class="slide2">
            <div id="music-content">
                <div id="music_albums">
                    <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                        <li><img src="album_test.png" /></li>
                        <li><img src="album_test.png" /></li>
                        <li><img src="album_test.png" /></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="music_vr">
                    <img src="light_vr.png" />
                </div>
                <div id="music_remixes">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide3">
        <h2>This is slide 3.</h2></div>
        <div class="slide4">
        <h2>This is slide 4.</h2></div>
    </div>
```

*album_example.png is 300x300 and album_test.png is 100x100

CSS:

```
@CHARSET "UTF-8";

h2 {
    color: #AAAAAA;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 150%;
}

p {
    color: #AAAAAA;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#container {
    width: 900px;
    height: 500px;
}

.slide1, .slide2, .slide3, .slide4 {
    width: 900px;
    height: 500px;
}

#news-content {
    width: 900px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0;
    max-height: 500px;
}

#news-img {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 100px 0 0;
    max-height: 300px;
}

#news-img-description {
    float: left;
    width: 295px;
    padding: 160px 15px 0 15px;
    max-height: 340px;
}

#news-vr {
    float: left;
    width: 1px;
    padding: 0 2px;
    max-height: 500px;
}

#news-feed {
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    max-height: 500px;
}

#music-content {
    width: 900;
    height: 500;
    margin: 0;
    max-height: 500px;
}

#music-albums {
    float: left;
    width: 447px;
    padding: 15px 0 0 0;
    max-height: 485px;
}

#music-vr {
    float: left;
    width: 1px;
    padding: 0 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: 500px;
}

#music-remixes {
    float: left;
    width: 448px;
    padding: 15px 0 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: 485px;
}

#music-albums, #music-remixes ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#music-albums, #music-remixes ul li
{
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. So answering your question properly this time:

You've got mixed-up underscores and dashes. Many IDs in your html use underscores where the corresponding CSS uses dashes, for example `music_vr` in the html and `music-vr` in your css.

That should at least get things to start making sense.

I did a bit of [clean-up on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/42rBF/17/) that shows that your float rules do in fact work, when you select the right element!

Tools like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and the [Element Inspector](http://www.threetipsaday.com/2008/12/debug-inspect-google-chrome-inspector/) in Firefox or Chrome/Safari really help with stuff like this -- you'd see right away that your rules weren't even applying to the elements and then it would be a quick process of elimination to figure out that some typos were causing that.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think that I made too much sense when I tried to explain it.  I don't actually move the slides at all.  They are all four located in the same spot, and I use JavaScript to hide 3 of them.  It's not the slides that are stacking vertically, but the content (divs) inside of them, which appear to be working inside the first slide but not the second.

Comment: Thank you so much, I hadn't even noticed that. Since the IDs were different, it wasn't even registering any of the style attributes.  Your help is much appreciated, and I will look at those tools!

Comment: Glad to help! Regarding the tools -- just right-click on _anything_ on _any web page_ in safari or chrome, and click "Inspect Element". Prepare to have your mind blown :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this:

```
.slide1, .slide2, .slide3, .slide4 {
   float: left;
   margin-left: 20px;
   background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

You need to add `float` property `<div>` that wraps content.

In your case it is slide1, slide2, ... `<div>`

Or second approach

```
.slide1, .slide2, .slide3, .slide4 {
   margin-left: 10px;
   display: inline-block;
   background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

**Note:** Working simplified example on [jsfiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/sdMD2/), [jsfiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/sdMD2/1/).

Comment: Actually all four of the slides are meant to be in the exact same spot, but only one of them being displayed at a time.  The problem I'm having is in the layout within the slide itself.

Comment: and? just use this and wrap them to one div, its your container and i you want to have containers next to another,just use float: left and it must work.

Comment: No, even with that nothing has changed. I still get in the second slide a list of three images centered and the spacer also centered below them.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a display: inline-block on the three divs, floating each of them to the left with relative positioning?

ie.

```
.all3divs {
position: relative;
float: left;
display: inline-block;
}
```

However, it looks like the middle 'spacing' div is a single pixel wide? if this is the case couldn't you remove it and give the first div a border-right: 1px; using the css3 border-image to place your spacer image?

This just seems cleaner and creates less overhead.

Comment: I just tried that, and unfortunately it didn't change anything.  Also, the spacing div's image is a 1px-wide vertical rule with a bilinear gradient, and has padding of 2px on the left and right.

Comment: the padding could be applied to the two divs (left and right), still eliminating the need for the third, mostly useless, div. It reminds me of tabled layouts and sounds dirty and inefficient. If whatever browser you are testing in won't allow the css3 border-image then perhaps you could make the left div have a background of the spacer image and just position it with a 2px offset on the right. then give the left div a 2px padding-right.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your divs get too little width. Try to reset your css:  http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/  .   Also try to lower widths of not working divs so that like 10 px of space in width is unused in you slide.

Comment: Sorry, that's not working either. In fact, the first slide's divs measure a total width of exactly 900 and it works, but the second one isn't working at all.